# Set parameterized COM property

Tags: python, com, pywin32

Getting a parameterized property (Ms Word's [`Options.DefaultFilePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/options-defaultfilepath-property-word)) works fine:

```
In [117]: o
Out[117]: <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Options instance at 0x43743792>

In [121]: o.DefaultFilePath(win32com.client.constants.wdDocumentsPath)
Out[121]: u'c:\\documents and settings\\user\\\u043c\u043e\u0438 \u0434\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u044b\\\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043c\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043a\u0438 \u0441\u0438'
```

But not setting:

```
In [122]: o.DefaultFilePath(win32com.client.constants.wdDocumentsPath)=".."
  File "<ipython-input-122-f2ed5d26c67c>", line 1
    o.DefaultFilePath(win32com.client.constants.wdDocumentsPath)=".."
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Also tried a suggested way from [C# Late Binding for Parameterized Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806073/c-sharp-late-binding-for-parameterized-property) :

```
In [123]: o.set_DefaultFilePath(win32com.client.constants.wdDocumentsPath,"..")
<...>
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library.Options instance at 0x43743792>' object has no attribute 'set_DefaultFilePath'
```

[Quick Start to Client side COM and Python](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html) also comes up empty.

Comment: Have you tried the bracketed form? `o.DefaultFilePath[win32com.client.constants.wdDocumentsPath] = ".."`

Comment: @MichaelGunter I tried it on getting. And got `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. Had no reason to believe they implemented `__setitem__` but not not `__getitem__`. Anyway, tried it now and got `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object does not support item assignment`.

Comment: Gotcha. I remember getting this to work, but it's been a few years. I would try `o.SetDefaultFilePath(...)` or `o.PutDefaultFilePath(...)` or `o.put_DefaultFilePath(...)`.

Comment: @MichaelGunter yes, by looking at `dir(o)`, I figured it out just now.

Comment: Ha! When in doubt...

Comment: @MichaelGunter it just never occurred to me they would do something as counterintuitive and nonstandard. And given my [recent problems getting objects with members filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243545/when-getting-document-object-from-word-application-object-its-members-are-not-f), I didn't expect there to be anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [160]: dir(o)
Out[160]:
['CLSID',
 'DefaultFilePath',
 'SetDefaultFilePath',
 'SetWPHelpOptions',
 <...>
```

Which suggests:

```
o.SetDefaultFilePath(win32com.client.constants.wdDocumentsPath,u"..")
```